# Need to integrate SSO in PHP with the help of Windows authentication

Tags: php, saml, windows-authentication, adfs

I am integrating SSO in my PHP project using onelogin/php_saml library. The thing is I am able to login using this library when linked to AD FS. But on windows system, it still asks for username and password to enter.

So I need to know how I can skip that login when using IE browser and within intranet. ie. Windows Authentication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE by default provides windows authentication when you are in a local intranet. Firstly you need to add the domain URL into **Internet Options => Security => Local intranet => Add to sites**.

Now if you are using onelogin/php_saml library for connecting to AD then make sure your setting **'security' => 'requestedAuthnContext' is set to false**.

Now make sure in AD setup, transform **rule is set to "Windows Account name"**

Comment: Let me know if you are still facing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Single sign on requires the adfs page link to be added in intranet zone, also make sure spn is registered for adfs service account.

From application prospective make sure the authentication is getting redirected to wia endpoint

Comment: Thanks Rishabh, That was requirement. I was stuck on that setting which needed to configure.